# How to Integrate SonarQube with QuickBuild?

Tags: jenkins, build, sonarqube, continuous-integration, quickbuild

We are currently using GitLab and QuickBuild for our Android Projects.
I have to integrate Sonarqube to have a pre check before every build.
I'm not able to get much information for quickbuild as most of the documentation is for Jenkins.

I can see that we can create steps in quickbuild and I would have to add one more step for sonar check and execute the sonar command.
But still I'm not very sure what is the best practice?

1. Where should I run the Sonar Server?
2. Where to add the sonar configuration files?
3. Any good documentation available?
4. Should I run the Sonar check on GitLab or QuickBuild? (Our build server is QuickBuild so it looks the better option)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ideally you should run sonar server on separate machine or you can use the same server on which quickbuild is running (depending upon java versions)
2. You can place sonar configuration file either in project directory or you can store it at any central location.
3. No official documentation for sonar and quickbuild integration.
4. Run sonar check on Buildserver.

Answer (score 0):

We chose to do the SonarQube check inside the Maven build (that runs on Quickbuild). A Maven plugin is available. If you use Gradle, this might do as well.